# Kentico getting data from multiple choice fields that use SQl causes GetValue to return a number instead of the actual name

Tags: content-management-system, field, kentico

I am hoping that there is just a method that I am missing.

Right now i am using `{% CurrentDocument.GetValue("marketType").Replace("|", ", ") #%}` which works totally fine if I have a list of options. As soon as I switched my field to get data by using :

```
SELECT 0 AS ItemID,  '-Select-' marketType
UNION ALL
SELECT ItemID, marketType FROM BBUS_MarketType
```

`{% CurrentDocument.GetValue("marketType").Replace("|", ", ") #%}` started displaying the number of the item instead of the item name itself.

Answer (score 1):

The list of choice has two parts "value,display". Your SELECT statement populate the value with ItemID which is number.

If you want to store the text, then it should be

```
SELECT '', '-Select-' UNION ALL SELECT marketType, marketType FROM BBUS_MarketType
```

populate the value with "marketType" instead of ID

Comment: For some reason, this gives me the error  [DataConnection.HandleError]: Query: SELECT 0 AS ItemID, '-Select-' marketType UNION ALL SELECT marketType, marketType FROM BBUS_MarketType Caused exception: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Civic' to data type int.

Comment: I think it has something to do with me trying to use this data for a custom filter

Comment: What is the Data type you have for the field? Text? What how is the ItemID been used?

Comment: Yup the data type is just text

Comment: It is just the generic ItemID that got created when I setup the tables through kentico

Comment: Does the marketType field on the table object also needs to be multiple choice?

Comment: SELECT '' as ItemID, do not put 0 there

Comment: SELECT '', '-Select-' UNION ALL SELECT marketType, marketType FROM BBUS_MarketType

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks for your help as well as everyone else!

Comment: There is no one else :) and please mark the answer correct as I have updated it.

Comment: The only issue left is when i use your method it displays the data perfectly, but it ends up breaking my filter. I assume this is because my ID's start at 1 and when I try to filter them without something taking spot 0 it breaks my filter.

Comment: What filter are you working with? Search filter or filter for SQL data?

Comment: The filter for SQL data, i am using a data source with a filter and a filtered repeater.

Comment: What does your data source expect from the filter? int or string?